# In hard disk drive, what exactly happen when we delete informations from our computer?

Tags: computer

I thought that this question should be asked at some computer/information websites, but since I was researching about physical concepts in hard disk drive, maybe asking here can be a good idea. :P

What I want to ask is, just as stated in title, what exactly happens?
My first idea was that the information saved in hard disk drive is represented as arragement of $[0,1]$, so when we delete it, it becomes like $$1111111 \to 11000001$$(partly removed). How can the head of a HDD recognizes it? or am I understanding the way of recording infos on hdd wrong?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, an 'ordinary' delete means that the areas where the file data resides are marked as available, i.e., the data isn't overwritten immediately.  But honestly, I don't see a physics related question here.

Comment: "Delete" is not a hard-drive concept.  Information on a modern HDD is organized as a fixed-size array of fixed-size _blocks_, where each block is a sequence of bytes.  The principal operations on an HDD are, `readBlock(n) ==> data`, and `writeBlock(n, data)`.  You can't "delete" a block, you can only overwrite a block with different data.

Comment: Why wouldn't a HDD be able to recognize a different pattern than the non-deleted one?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's not about physics but internal storage of a hardcore.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about physics but internal storage of a hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

in the classic sense, when you delete a file, you delete not the contents on a sector of the disc but instead the address of the file. the computer therefore doesn't "know" where to find the file, and will eventually write a new file on top of it.

you can also run a program which overwrites or erases "deleted" files so as to prevent them from being read by someone who knows how to extract data off a disc without an address.